# Building Queries on JSON documents in Watson Discovery Service

Tags: json, training-data, watson, watson-discovery, watson-knowledge-studio

We are trying to add structured data to Watson Discovery Service and querying the same. Is there anything like fuzzy search available while fetching the results? For example, if I have a field **firstname with value john** in one document & query with **firstname:jon**, discovery does not give results. If i try **firstname::!jon** (means not exact match) it gives all the records, even those that have nothing similar to john. Is there any way to train discovery service to identify such entities? How to improve the results of these queries with training? Improve results option was available only for Natural Language queries.

Would it be helpful to use Watson Knowledge Studio for Discovery Service with JSON documents? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The query expansion option that's mentioned below should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

To make Watson Discovery know that John is synonymous with Jon you've got two options:

1. You can use the query expansion feature and make an expansion for Jon => John. See the documentation on query expansions here: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/discovery/using.html#query-expansion
2. Or use some of the fuzzy matching features like the string variation operator https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/discovery/query-operators.html#variation or the wildcard operator: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/discovery/query-operators.html#Wildcard